# Join on nested obj attribute in JSONB column along and a varchar column

Tags: postgresql, json, postgresql-12

I have table `connections` where both columns are `varchar`:

```
+---------+---------------+
| user_id | other_user_id |
+=========+===============+
| foo     | bar           |
+---------+---------------+
| baz     | asdf          |
+---------+---------------+
```

And table `events` where `user_id` references `connections.user_id`:

```
+---------+----------------+
| user_id | payload        |
+=========+================+
| foo     | {              |
|         |   otherUser: { |
|         |     id: "bar"  |
|         |   }            |
|         | }              |
+---------+----------------+
| baz     | {              |
|         |   otherUser: { |
|         |     id: "asdf" |
|         |   }            |
|         | }              |
+---------+----------------+
```

I would like to JOIN the tables on `connections.user_id = events.user_id` and `connections.other_user_id = events.payload.otherUser->>id`

Though, I'm not sure how to access the `id` field in the nested `otherUser` object in the JSONB column.

This is the most I've come up with:

```
SELECT * FROM events ev 
JOIN connections con ON con.user_id = ev.user_id AND con.other_user_id = ev.payload->otherUser->>id
```

also tried `con.other_user_id = (ev.payload)::jsonb->otherUser->>id`

for these ^ two options I get "column `otheruser` doesn't exist".

Then also tried:

`con.other_user_id = text(jsonb_extract_path(ev.payload::jsonb, 'otherUser', 'id'))`

Which throws no error but also no rows are returned.

But I get error about the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys for the `->` or `->>` operators need to be supplied as strings:

```
SELECT * 
FROM events ev 
  JOIN connections con 
    ON con.user_id = ev.user_id 
   AND con.other_user_id = ev.payload -> 'otherUser' ->> 'id'
```

Or use the `#>>` operator and pass an array:

```
SELECT * 
FROM events ev 
  JOIN connections con 
    ON con.user_id = ev.user_id 
   AND con.other_user_id = ev.payload #>> '{otherUser,id}';
```

Which is basically the same as using `jsonb_extract_path_text`

```
SELECT * 
FROM events ev 
  JOIN connections con 
    ON con.user_id = ev.user_id 
   AND con.other_user_id = jsonb_extract_path_text(ev.payload, 'otherUser','id');
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=aaf3cedfc003f4a6c3c02d0eb98484ef)